# Hibernate/H2 @OneToMany "Referential integrity constraint violation" on remove of child?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, h2, referential-integrity

Hello I have a rather simple relationship. 
A Patient can have several Measurements. I used a H2 file database and Hibernate.

The Problem:
When I try to remove a Measurement from a Patient I get a the following Error.

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_O423U89KR6K78NNG1PO0ISDF6: PUBLIC.PATIENTVO_MEASUREMENTVO FOREIGN KEY(MEASUREMENTS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MEASUREMENTVO(ID) (X'3c2b9ee868f645c5a5a743c2a409ab5e')"; SQL statement:
delete from MeasurementVO where id=? [23503-185]
```

The Patient part of the Relationship:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "patient", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<MeasurementVO> getMeasurements() {
    return measurements;
}
```

The Measurement Part of the Relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
public PatientVO getPatient() {
    return patient.get();
}
```

The function which should delete a Measurement:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean removeMeasurementFromPatient(PatientVO patientVO, MeasurementVO measurementVO) {
        EntityManager manager = emProvider.get();
        PatientVO patientAlreadyInDB = manager.find(PatientVO.class, patientVO.getPatientId());

        if (patientAlreadyInDB != null) {
            patientAlreadyInDB.getMeasurements().removeIf(measurement -> measurement.getId().equals(measurementVO.getId()));
            manager.merge(patientAlreadyInDB);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the Persistence XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="db" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>ch.fhnw.ima.doggait.vo.PatientVO</class>
        <class>ch.fhnw.ima.doggait.vo.MeasurementVO</class>
        <class>ch.fhnw.ima.doggait.vo.MeasurementAttributesVO</class>
        <class>ch.fhnw.ima.doggait.vo.TimeMark</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
           <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:db"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:./database/dogdatabase"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Does somebody has a hint why I am not able to remove a Measurement from a patient and then persist him/her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the name of the table whose constraint is being violated (`PATIENTVO_MEASUREMENTVO`), seems like you have an intermediate table to implement the relation. This is normally used in many to many relationships.

Being a one to many relationship why not just adding a foreign key from the Measurement to Patient?

Comment: The thing is, I did not create the Tables manually. Hibernate created the tables based on the annotations. Maybe my annotations are incorrect, but thats what im trying to find out.

Comment: Can you try removing the `mappedBy` attribute in the `@OneToMany` annotation of `getMeasurements()` as well as the `@JoinColumn` in `getPatient()`?

Comment: Thank you. I removed JoinColumn before and it had no effect. But removing JoinColumn as well as mappedBy did the trick. Im now able to delete the measurements. I begin to believe it is sometimes better to write DataBase access classes and perform SQL queries instead of using ORM. Hibernate is always pretty cool until you get some errors. Than it gets hard to debug, because you dont know how exactly your tables and relationships look like. At least if you are a noob in this field like me.